# Unable to display border over hovering of menu item

Tags: css

I am just having an issue with my CSS. I am basically trying to display a red border around a menu item when it's hovered over.

The issue with the CSS below is that all of the links are showed red bordered (no hover). What do I need to change in order to get show the border over hover?

Below is CSS code:

```
.page-template-default #mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link, .product-template-default #mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link, .archive #mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link, .single #mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link, k .post-type-archive #mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link a:hover:after {
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

It points to this part of the code:

```
...
<a class="mega-menu-link" href="https://www.test.com" tabindex="0">Test</a>
```

Screenshot of code:

[image]

Comment: attached any image or full code...

Comment: this is only the HTML part can you possible to add a snippet code to understand what exactly to do...

Answer (score 0):

I will be needing more context to understand why it is not working on your case, But basically a hover on CSS works like this,

You have an HTML element,

```
<a class="mega-menu-link" href="https://www.test.com" tabindex="0">Test</a>
```

To hover effect add this to the CSS,

```
.mega-menu-link:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  //and other properties and values you want to change on hover
 }
```

It is wise to add hover to the parent and the effect to the child, e.g.

HTML,

```
<li class="parent">
 <a class="mega-menu-link" href="https://www.test.com" tabindex="0">Test</a>
</li>
```

CSS,

```
.parent:hover .mega-menu-link{
   border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

Comment: Hey, I added a screenshot of the code to make it easier to add the parent. I tried the first part of your answer but sadly it did not show on hover

Comment: Please, show the styles also. It seems like a WordPress website. May be you can give us the link to your website? I think your selector is unable to select the desired element, may be it is being overridden? Try adding a border without the hover state, if it is working, give it a transparent color, `border: 1px solid transparent;`; then change the color in hovered state, `border: 1px solid red`.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS given seems to encompass all the possibilities for the a.mega-menu-link elements, whether hovered or not.

Try replacing it with just

```
a.mega-menu-link:hover {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Note, there is part of the original CSS which mentions :after which suggests there is a pseudo element attached to the a element. Without seeing more of the code I cannot tell whether some styling of such an element is necessary, or indeed whether there is a pseudo element at all.

Comment: Hey, thank yuo for your answer. Sadly it still did not work

Comment: Could you say what did not work means? Are you still getting red border round everything? If so I think we need to see all your code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it does not show a border when I hover over it. I uploaded a screenshot of the code through inspect as it's code from a wordpress plugin

Comment: Could you go into your browsers dev tools and inspect an a element to see exactly what CSS is being applied to them. There must be some other settings we haven’t seen yet.